# Edit and Save Pivot Table in Database in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server, ajax

I want to create an ASP.Net web page which will have one DropDownList control and upon changing the selection of it. Pivot table should be created. 
The Column Headers and Row Headers of this table should come from Database. The values shown in this table will also be retrieved from Database with respect to the corresponding Column Header and Row Header.
This table values should be editable  and upon "SAVE" button click the Data in values should be saved in database for corresponding Column Header and Row Header.
example:

```
           |   Lot1   |   Lot2  |   Lot3 |  ...
---------------------------------------------
Product1   |    100   |  2000   |   3000 |  ...
---------------------------------------------
Product2   |    1000  |  3000   |   4000 |  ...
---------------------------------------------
Product3   |    3500  |  6000   |   4500 |  ...
---------------------------------------------
```

.
.
These values should be editable and upon save button click these should save in database with respect to Lot number and Product.

Comment: What have u tried!!?

Comment: you sound like a client:)show us the code you have written.

Comment: I used following code..[link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/46486/Pivoting-DataTable-Simplified) But here i can only view the data in table but i want to update the same. So these vales in table should be editable and I also want to save the same data against the column and row header.. Hope this makes the picture clear